# Parse a long JSON string throws "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected String"

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a c#.net MVC application.  I am using jQuery UI autocomplete.  I have created a valid JSON string to send to the autocomplete and add it to the view like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    autoCompleteParams[@Model.Id] = jQuery.parseJSON(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ParamValueListJson)));
    // Handles onchange for autocomplete
    $reports.initParamList('@Model.Id');
});
```

When I check the value of `ParamValueListJson` and run it through a `JSON` validation, it is a valid string.  However, it is very long.  When pasted into Word, it is 98 pages and 424,638 characters (including spaces).

When I look at the html returned to the view specifically checking the resulting value I can see that the character count dropped to 31,424.  Because it is truncated the `JSON` is not valid and I get the error "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected String"

If I limit the records returned, then it all works again. However, I can't do that.  I need all values as an option.

What is the best way to handle this?  Can I ensure the full `JSON` string is returned to the view?  Is there another way to create the Object for the auto-complete?  Or, do I need to artificially limit the length of the `JSON` and then combine the results in the view?

Any help with this is appreciated.  So far, Google searches have been unhelpful.

#### UPDATE

I just looked a little closer and now see that the full string is getting passed to the view.  The data returned in the AJAX call has the full string.  However, when it executes `jQuery.parseJSON` that is when it is getting truncated.

#### UPDATE 2

After removing the `"` found in one of the value strings, it all works as expected.  Apparently the string wasn't getting truncated, it is just that the `data` param visible in the Developer Tools wasn't showing the full string.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the string so long?  Surely this is an instance where some compartmentalization would be beneficial.

Comment: Generally it isn't, but in this case the autocomplete is to help the user select an existing part number.  In my test db, that is 5900 parts, but my customers can have 10s of thousands.  The autocomplete is setup so that if they have >1000 they must type at least 1 character, >2000 then 2.  That is generally sufficient for a fast selection....if I can get it to render.

Comment: While I realize that JSON isn't really unlimited...I did expect it to allow more than 31K characters.

Comment: @davids , seem like what you're doing should be the direction, require several keys depending on size of db, so it'll limit the results ...

Comment: @Noctis Good suggestion, but it seems that with his current requirement he can't.

Comment: @davids What about returning the data payload as an alternative format, namely text/html and parsing the response on the client?  Though mind you, with such a large string, you'll have some performance issues no matter what I'd expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you should have a string that long or not is a good question (and one you should answer), but a separate topic.

In my experience, if you are getting the "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected String" error, there is some unescaped character in the string causing it to fail (e.g. '";:).

Given that the shorter string works, perhaps it is one of the records at the end of the full results with the invalid character.

The truncation you are seeing may simply be the result of how you are accessing the string in the browser and not a limitation on the size of the JSON string.  Given your last UPDATE that the full string is there, I speculate that the string sent to the parser isn't truncated.

I suggest that you carefully look at the full string and check for unescaped characters in the values.

Comment: If you had read my question, you would see that the string is valid.  It isn't helpful to be sent on a wild goose chase.  

However, upon closer inspection I can see that there actually was an invalid character. ;)

Thank you for trusting your experience and sharing!  I am not sure what I tested originally, but it obviously wasn't the full string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't display thousands of records at a time.  There is no reason to to return thousands.  Just let the autocomplete make the ajax call on its own, as [demonstrated](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) on the jQuery UI web site.

Make sure that your server-side ajax endpoint filters the result set down to something reasonable.. like say 20-25 records.

Some hints:  Your MVC controller method will want to return a JsonResult instead of a View.
Also, be sure to set the JsonResult to allow HttpGet (as a property of the JsonResult object):

Something like this (VB, but you can figure it out):

```
$('#txtSearchTerms').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Context.Request.Url.Scheme://@Context.Request.Url.Host:@Context.Request.Url.Port/Ajax/ProductSearch/' + $('#txtSearchTerms').val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: iitem.Name,
                        value: item.ProductID,
                        id: item.ProductID
                    }
                }))     //  response
            }           //  success
        })              //  ajax
    }                   //  source function
});

<HttpGet>
Public Function ProductSearch(term As String) As JsonResult
  Dim payload As SomeModel = Nothing
  Using database As WebDataContext = New WebDataContext
    database.Configuration.CreateProxies = False
    payload = (From p In database.Products Where p.Name.Trim.ToLower.StartsWith(term.Trim.ToLower) Select p).Take(25).ToList
  End Using

  Return New JsonResult With {.Data = payload, .JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet}
End Function
```